# Git interactive rebase reword - commit position in history changed

Tags: git, git-rebase

My history before the rebase (reword):

```
A-B--------G----------L          
   \        \       
    C-D-E-F  H-I-J-K
```

I wanted to reword G and L so I checkout their branch and did a rebase rewording them, this is what I ended up with:

```
A-B------------------------G*-L*
   \        \
    C-D-E-F  G-H-I-J-K
```

Here's an image to illustrate the current tree:

[image: Current git tree]

Now let me explain better. Before rebasing. One of the top two commits was next to the second branch. After rebasing it was updated.

So, can someone explain why did that happen? And if I can fix that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reword is the same as edit so commit's hash and commit's time will be changed.

After rebase your tree should look like that (your tree in the question body is wrong I suppose):

```
A-B------------------------G*-L*[master]
   \        \
    C-D-E-F  G-H-I-J-K[branch2]
```

Note that commit G is still in `branch2`. To fix that you should rebase `branch2` to new commit G*.

```
git rebase --onto <G* hash> <G hash> branch2
```

After that G commit will be gone:

```
A-B--------G*----------------L*[master]
   \        \
    C-D-E-F  H-I-J-K[branch2]
```

Comment: My tree is exactly correct in question. C-D-E-F is a branch that I didn't merge, same goes for H-I-J-K, which was based on G.

Comment: Your tree cannot be correct or some your steps are missing in the description. After changing G commit branch H-I-J-K will still remain on G commit (old), and there will be a new G commit which is followed by L*. My tree demonstrates this.

Comment: I added an image to explain further.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're actually right, G moved down to the branch2 tree. So your tree is correct. I'll try your solution.